# PHP Max Input Vars: 1000 - Recommended Value: 1500 in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I am trying to install a theme's demo website in WordPress and it says:

```
PHP Max Input Vars: 1000 - Recommended Value: 1500.
Max input vars limitation will truncate POST data such as menus. See: Increasing max input vars limit.
```

Here I am using xampp server. In my `php.ini`:

```
max_input_time=60

; Maximum input variable nesting level
; http://php.net/max-input-nesting-level
;max_input_nesting_level = 64

; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
;max_input_vars = 3000

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit=512M
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semicolon infront of `;max_input_vars = 3000`.

The semicolon ';' on the ini file is similar to commenting out the line.

As per your theme's recommendation it can be set as 1500.